# PDDocument.save(file) is very slow

Tags: android, pdfbox

Using [PDFBox-Android](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android), I'm currently loading my PDF into a `PDDocument` like so:

```
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();
```

Then I am timing the `save()` function like this:

```
long substart = System.currentTimeMillis();
pdDoc.save(file);
Log.d("formData", "save took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - substart) / 1000);
```

The save method is taking up to 10 seconds on a Nextbook NXA8QC116R (4-6 seconds on my HTC One M8) to save a PDF file that is only 93kb in size. I've also tried using a `BufferedOutputStream` to save the file, but that didn't seem to help.

Is this a flaw in the library, or is there something that I can do to help speed up the saving method for small files?

Comment: Use Traceview to get a better sense of where your time is being spent.

Comment: what is the `type` of the object `file` in your code?

Comment: Make sure you are following good code practices. Check if you are calling this set of code as a function in a for/while loop...